# Android project broken in Eclipse after ant build

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I had a project working in Eclipse completely, but after compiling it with ant in order to use Proguard to obfuscate the code the entire project fell apart.

The project consists of a single package containing two main activities and 4 helper classes to handle databases and such. After using ant the activities work fine but Eclipse cannot find the helper classes and won't build. Even if I explicitly import the classes the error I get is 
`The import com.ts.routeTracking.DataHelper cannot be resolved` while further mentions of the class get the error `DataHelper cannot be resolved to a type`.

How can I get Eclipse and ant to work together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This probably means that ant and Eclipse are using the same output directory.  You can alter the output directory by adding this to your `build.properties` or `ant.properties` file.

```
out.dir=bin-ant
```

To get Eclipse working again, select Project → Clean.  That should cause a rebuild of all the files that Eclipse works with.